# how to get concurrent modification exception arraylist for custom object

Tags: arraylist

As per java doc Java.util.ArrayList throws concurrentModificationException when we change data structure of it after creating iterator on it ,but it is not throwing same when i ran below code

```
    ArrayList<Employee> lsEmp=new ArrayList<Employee>();
    Employee indra = new Employee(101,"Indra");
    Employee ankit =new Employee(102,"Ankit");
    Employee bhanu= new Employee(103,"bhanu");

    lsEmp.add(indra);
    lsEmp.add(ankit);
    //lsEmp.add(bhanu);

    System.out.println("Employee list"+lsEmp);

    Iterator<Employee> it =lsEmp.iterator();
    if (it.hasNext()){
        Employee temp =  it.next();
        if(temp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("Indra"));{
            System.out.println("inside if condition");
        //temp.setName("Indra Mohan Joshi");
        lsEmp.remove(temp);
        lsEmp.add(bhanu);
        }
    }

    System.out.println("list after loop"+lsEmp);
```

could you please help me to understand logic behind this?
Thanks in advance  !

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `if (it.hasNext())` by a `while (it.hasNext())`, and you'll see the exception appear, because you'll then ask the iterator to go to the next element *after* you've modified the list. The Iterator won't throw an exception if it's not called.